# How do you define a function during dynamic Python type creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, metaclass, class-method

(This is in Python 3 btw)

Okay so say we use `type()` as a class constructor:

`X = type('X', (), {})`

What I'm trying to find is how would `type()` accept a function as an argument and allow it to be callable?

I'm looking for an example of how this could be accomplished. Something along the lines of:

```
>>> X = type('X', (), {'name':'World', 'greet':print("Hello {0}!".format(name))}
>>> X.greet()
Hello World!
```

Comment: What does this have to do with dynamic programming?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my overall project has to do with dynamic programming. I chose tags revolving around the main purpose behind the question so I would attract those who could answer with that mindset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function.  In your code, you call the function, and pass the result.

Try:

```
def print_hello(self):
    print("Hello {0}!".format(self.name))

X = type('X', (), {'name':'World', 'greet': print_hello})
```

Comment: Oh so the function needs to be defined beforehand? That helps with that part, now I've gotta find a way to dynamically define a function. most likely with `eval()` i'm sure